# Using OleDbDataAdapter and DataSet to update Access.mdb

Tags: c#, ms-access

I am attempting to update a simple ms access database. I get an Exception on certain tables that, after searching, I found [Microsoft Support - Syntax Error](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/892608). I believe it means that one of the column names uses a reserved word. This seems to be the case, since all the tables update except the ones with "GUID" as one of the column names, a reserved word. This page also states that I should be using a OleDbAdapter and DataSet, which should solve the problem. Unfortunately I cannot change the name of the column. That is beyond my control, so I have to work with what is given me.

I haven't had to do work with databases much, and everything I know I've learned from examples from the internet (probably bad ones at that). So what is the proper way to update a database using OleDbAdapter and dataSet?

I don't think I should be using DataTable or OleDbCommandBuilder, and I believe the solution has something to do with parameters. But my googleing skills are weak.

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; " +
                            Data Souce=" + source);
conn.Open();
OleDbAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * From " + table, conn);
OleDbCommandBuiler cmdBuiler = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter);
DataSet = new DatSet();
adapter.InsertCommand = cmdBuilder.GetInertCommand(true); // Is this necessary?
adapter.Fill( dataSet, table);
DataTable dataTable = dataSet.Tables[table]; // Do I need a DataTable?
DataRow row = dataTable.
row [ attribute ] = field; // Do this for all attributes/fields. I think this is wrong.
dataTable.rows.Add(row);
adapter.Update(dataTable); //<--"Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement." Exception
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem may be that the column names (especially those whose name are reserved words) should be surrounded by square brackets.  The OleDbCommandBuilder, when it creates its own InsertCommand, doesn't surround the names with brackets, so a solution is to manually define the OleDbDataAdapter's InsertCommand:

```
adapter.InsertCommand = new OleDbCommand(String.Format("INSERT INTO {0} ([GUID], [fieldName]) Values (@guid,@fieldName);", table), conn);
```

Defining parameters for each column and then manually adding the parameter's values;

```
adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@guid",row["GUID"]));
```

So summing up, for the tables which have a column named "GUID", you should try something like the following:

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + 
"Data Souce=" + source);                          
conn.Open(); 

OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * From " + table, conn);
OleDbCommandBuilder cmdBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter);

adapter.InsertCommand = new OleDbCommand(String.Format("INSERT INTO {0} ([GUID], [fieldName]) Values (@guid,@fieldName);", table), conn);

DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(table);
adapter.Fill( dataTable);
DataRow row = dataTable.NewRow();
row [ fieldName ] = fieldValue;
// eg: row [ "GUID" ] = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); // Do this for all attributes/fields.
dataTable.Rows.Add(row);

adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@fieldName",row[fieldName]));
// eg: adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@guid",row["GUID"]));

adapter.Update(dataTable);
```

Comment: This did the trick, except I had to still use the DataSet. Otherwise it would throw an exception at `adapter.Fill`. The exception was `System.ArgumentException` `{"Object is not an ADODB.RecordSet or an ADODB.Record.\r\nParameter name: adodb"}`. Thanks Matt.

Comment: Thanks, it was my first answer on SO, so I'm glad it worked out for you!

Comment: If you are using `OleDbCommandBuilder` you can use `cmdBuilder.QuotePrefix = "[";` and  `cmdBuilder.QuoteSuffix = "]";`.

Answer (score 0):

As to problem #1. Try doing a full qualification of the column name i.e. table.columnName (that fixes the problem in MySQL so maybe it does in Access) also, try putting [ ] around the column name.

Select * is usually a poor option to specifying the column names and using aliases. For example use Select Column1 as 'Column1', Column2 as 'Column2' ....
this makes working with your dataset and datatable much easier as you can access the column by its alias instead of by column indexes.

I find that the DataAdapter is much more useful for filling datasets than for actually modifying a database. I recommend something like:

```
string updateQuery = "Update ..... Where ...."; //do your magic here
OldDbcommand command = new OleDbCommand(updateQuery);
command.Connection = conn;
conn.Open();
con.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

You could fill your dataset with the adapter and then do as I just did to execute your update commands on the DB.

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start would be using DataSetDesigner and Typed DataSets to start
try this walk through : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171893(v=vs.80).aspx

A good longterm approach is to use Sql Server Express instead, then you'll have a choice of using : Entity Framework, Linq To Sql or Still keep using the DataSetDesigner and Typed DataSets.