# insert into ms access database

Tags: c#, ms-access

I use the following code to insert a record from one database to another but it doesn't work. I tried the query in MS-ACCESS 2007 and it works fine but it doesn't work when called programmatically from my C# code?

```
string query_insert = "INSERT INTO Questionnaires_Table(BranchName,Factor,Region,Branch_ID,Current_Date,No_Employees) "
+ "SELECT BranchName,Factor,Region,Branch_ID,Current_Date,No_Employees "
+ "FROM Questionnaires_Table IN '" + dialog.FileName + "' Where Branch_ID = " + textBox1.Text ;

dbConnDest.Open();

OleDbDataAdapter dAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
OleDbCommand cmd_insert = new OleDbCommand(query_insert, dbConnDest);

dAdapter.InsertCommand = cmd_insert;

textBox2.Text = query_insert.ToString();

dbConnDest.Close();
```

When I take the the content of `query_insert` in ms access, it works fine.

Comment: What exception do you get?  Does the executing account have access to the external database?

Comment: What exactly does not work? Do you get an exception?

Comment: **warning** your code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: i don't get any exception

Comment: Just nothing happen to the destination database

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to use

```
cmd_insert.executeNonQuery()
```

Comment: when  i try this got an exception of syntax error in INSERT INTO

Comment: That means your sql syntax is wrong. In this situation, I'd put up some breakpoints to determine the value of query_insert and paste it into your ms access db to see if it works

Comment: I see, then try using textbox2.Text = cmd_insert.executeScalar()

Comment: And like HansUp said, you should remove the comma in the SELECT statement

Comment: Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: my bad. textbox2.Text = cmd_insert.executeScalar().toString()

Comment: with executenonquery and executescalar i got an exception for insert into syntax

Answer (score 1):

Remove the comma after the last field name in the `SELECT` list.

```
"SELECT BranchName,Factor,Region,Branch_ID,Current_Date,No_Employees"
```

Answer (score 0):

dAdapter.Update();
should do the trick

Comment: you created an insert statement but you didn't execute it.
An example can be read here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874887/using-oledbdataadapter-and-dataset-to-update-access-mdb)
You can leave out the DataTable related code if you want.

Answer (score 0):

This seems suspect:

```
 " Where Branch_ID = " + textBox1.Text ;
```

Does `textBox1` contain a numeric ID?  Does the ID that is entered exist in the source database?

I would 1) do a check that the ID exists and warn the user if it doesn't, and 2) change the query to use paramters instead of concatenating SQL.

What would happen if your company opened a branch with the ID of

```
"1; DROP TABLE Branches"
```

Comment: i use parameters but still got the same problem