# insert into ms access db from another database with c# code

Tags: c#, ms-access

I use the following code to insert a record from one database to another but it doesn't work. I tried the query in `MS-ACCESS 2007` and it works fine but it doesn't work when called programmatically from my `C#` code?

```
string query_insert = "INSERT INTO Questionnaires_Table(BranchName,Factor,Region,Branch_ID,Current_Date,No_Employees) "
    + "SELECT BranchName,Factor,Region,Branch_ID,Current_Date,No_Employees "
    + "FROM Questionnaires_Table IN '" + dialog.FileName + "' Where Branch_ID = " + textBox1.Text ;

dbConnDest.Open();


   OleDbDataAdapter dAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
   OleDbCommand cmd_insert = new OleDbCommand(query_insert, dbConnDest);

   dAdapter.InsertCommand = cmd_insert;
   cmd_insert.ExecuteNonQuery();

dbConnDest.Close();
```

When I take the the content of `query_insert` in ms access, it works fine

It throws

> INSERT INTO syntax error exception in line 
>   cmd_insert.ExecuteNonQuery();

EDIT

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication4
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();

            dialog.Title = "select database";



            if ((dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) && (textBox1.Text == ""))
            {
                    MessageBox.Show("insert reference year", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            else
            {




                    OleDbConnection dbConnDest;
                    dbConnDest = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= C:\Users\SystemA.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;");

                    try
                    {



                        string query_insert = "INSERT INTO Questionnaires_Table(BranchName,Factor,Region,Branch_ID,Current_Date,No_Employees) "
                                               + "SELECT BranchName,Factor,Region,Branch_ID,Current_Date,No_Employees "
                                               + "FROM Questionnaires_Table1 IN '" + dialog.FileName + "' Where ReferenceYear = " + textBox1.Text + ";";




                        dbConnDest.Open();



                        OleDbCommand cmd_insert = new OleDbCommand(query_insert, dbConnDest);

                        try
                        {
                            cmd_insert.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                        catch (Exception g)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(g.ToString());
                        }



                        textBox2.Text = query_insert.ToString();

                        dbConnDest.Close();
                    }
                    catch (Exception h)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(h.ToString());
                    }



                }


        }

    }
}
```

EDIT

Comment: possible duplicate of [insert into ms access database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15618165/insert-into-ms-access-database)

Comment: Are you sure you are using IN correctly?

Comment: Where do you get that syntax `FROM table IN filename` ?

Comment: In Access can you use IN to point to a file location?

Comment: i try it and works perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a different syntax [in this Microsoft forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/c7cbc0e5-e7f6-44c5-a382-1595034faa44/)

```
  INSERT INTO [AccessTable] SELECT * FROM [MS Access;DATABASE=D:\My Documents\db2.mdb].[Table2]
```

so you could try this

```
string query_insert = "INSERT INTO Questionnaires_Table " +
    "(BranchName,Factor,Region,Branch_ID,[Current_Date],No_Employees) " +
    "SELECT BranchName,Factor,Region,Branch_ID,[Current_Date],No_Employees " +
    "FROM [MS Access;DATABASE=" + dialog.FileName  + "].Questionnaires_Table " +
    "Where Branch_ID = @branch";

dbConnDest.Open();
OleDbCommand cmd_insert = new OleDbCommand(query_insert, dbConnDest);
cmd_insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@branch", textBox1.Text);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Tested with `"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"`

However, with more research it is clear that the syntax error given is due to the presence of a [reserved keyword](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321266) CURRENT_DATE. This could be resolved encapsulating the field name with square brackets.

By the way, the IN syntax works as well once cured the problem of CURRENT_DATE.

Comment: i use IN because the source database is different from the destination database

Comment: i'm using MS ACCESS 2007 .accdb i test this but still nothing happens thank you anyway for your courage

Comment: I have tested the code above (MS Access;.....) and it works with two different database and with ACE provider.

Comment: of course no, I have set up two different databases with a simple table and some data. Then I have done the transfer with the syntax like the one above. The important thing is: REMOVE the IN, add [MS Access;DATABASE=.......YOUR FILE.....;

Comment: my databases has different structure does this made the problem?

Comment: No because you have specified the fields to grab from the external table through the SELECT. I was thinking, do you put the Whole pathname with the backslash separator in that IN ..... ?

Comment: i try your example and when i get the variable query_string and put it manually in ms access works perfect too but not in my program

Comment: If you like I could look at your project. Share a link to a public repository like dropbox, skydrive, gdrive, mediafire or whatever you like.

Comment: where do you want to send it??

Comment: Upload to a sharing site like mediafire, skydrive, gdrive,dropbox and post the link here

Comment: give me your email its easier

Comment: I can't believe it. CURRENT_DATE is a reserved keyword. Need to encapsulate it with square brackets. I will update the answer. By the way, works also with the IN

Comment: thank you very much that was the problem i couldn't imagine that answer for this problem

Comment: i can't vote for you but you got my vote anyway thank you very much

Comment: It was fun, now I go to sleep. Thanks anyway (however it's stressing that the most upvoted answer is clearly wrong, well, let's go)

Comment: +1 for the revelation that CURRENT_DATE is a reserved keyword, did not know that!

Answer (score 1):

you are missing 'values' keyword in query_insert.

Comment: the values is the SELECT query

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really familiar with ms access queries but I think you shouldn't use OleDbDataAdapter. The code should look similar to following:

```
string query_insert = "INSERT INTO Questionnaires_Table(BranchName,Factor,Region,Branch_ID,Current_Date,No_Employees) "
    + "SELECT BranchName,Factor,Region,Branch_ID,Current_Date,No_Employees "
    + "FROM Questionnaires_Table IN '" + dialog.FileName + "' Where Branch_ID = " + textBox1.Text ;

dbConnDest.Open();

OleDbCommand cmd_insert = new OleDbCommand(query_insert, dbConnDest);
cmd_insert.ExecuteNonQuery();

dbConnDest.Close();
```

Comment: did you know any other way to insert a record from one database table to other database table?

Comment: @user2183831, yes but I didn't use ms-access for a while. What I'm wandering is it is there any way to set db schema explicitly in access? Because it looks like you're inserting into the same table from which you query.

Comment: it just the same table name

Answer (score 0):

Like others said, thats a SQL syntax problem. You are missing the VALUES keyword, look:

```
INSERT INTO TABLENAME (COL1, COL2, COL2) VALUES (VAL1, VAL2, VAL3)
```

Where is your VALUES keyword?

Comment: @user2183831:
First: try to write the VALUES keyword, like:
INSERT INTO (COL1,COL2,COL3) VALUES (SELECT (COL1,COL2,COL3) FROM...)

Second: try to use SqlParam in your Command object instead of concatenating strings.

Will be better to you to find the errors source.

Comment: i still got the same exception

Comment: VALUES is the SELECT query